# A dynamic link library(DLL) initialization routine failed.(Exception from HRESULT:0x8007045A) Error,while using Pinvoke

Tags: c#, wpf, pinvoke

I  have a WPF application which use pinvoke for calling a C++ method dll name as Project1.dll.when I am installing and using it on windows 7 it is working fine but on windows 8.1 it is giving “Unable to load DLL'C:\MyApp3\project1.dll':A dynamic link library(DLL) initialization routine failed.(Exception from HRESULT:0x8007045A)”. Project1.dll is placed in C:\MyApp3 folder. What is cause of this error can any one suggest?

Answer (score 1):

That's a COM error code wrapping [this Win32 error](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681383.aspx#ERROR_DLL_INIT_FAILED):

> **ERROR_DLL_INIT_FAILED**      1114 (0x45A)
>
> A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.

It means the the DLL you loaded, or one of its dependencies returned `FALSE` from its [`DllMain`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682583.aspx).

You'll need to do some debugging to find out why. You might start by looking for `DllMain` in the DLL and any dependent DLLs.